# Insert image in comment reply

Tags: images, comments, uploads

I have searched everywhere but can not find a plugin that allows users to upload an image into their Reply to a comment. It is a photographic blog so has to have this ability.

I did try a couple but none actually worked! Anyone any ideas please?

Comment: Try this one, it allows you to attach anything - even images, and if it's image to create thumbnails and show them in comment. http://wordpress.org/plugins/comment-attachment/

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for could be a `wp_editor()` in comment form :

```
 wp_editor( $comment->comment_content, 'content', array( 'media_buttons' => true, 'tinymce' => false, 'quicktags' => $quicktags_settings ) );
```

Comment: My users aren´t techies but thanks for the thought. no idea what that code is for.

Comment: The problem is it could turn off-topic (plugin recommandation) if you do not want to code